# jQuery Mobile data-role=page within a data-role=page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

I have a parent div with `data-role="page"` and its content has its own `data-role="page"` as well. Is it possible to navigate within the content area's `data-role="page"` without making the parent div navigate?

For example,

```
<div id="main" data-role="page">

title goes here

<div id="content_1" data-role="subpage">

 content goes here

</div>
<!--/#content_1 -->

<div id="content_2" data-role="subpage">

 content goes here

</div>
<!--/#content_2 -->

</div>
<!-- /#main -->
```

Basically I want to navigate only between `#content_1` and `#content_2` while `#main` will just stay put/remain as well as the Title.

Comment: Perhaps just hide/show the 2 `subpage` divs via jQuery based on your particular page logic i.e. on click or some other event `$('#content_1').toggle(); $('#content_2').toggle();` remember to also add `#content_2{display:none;}` ass CSS to begin with.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker make that an answer so that I can +1 it

Comment: I want it to have the same transition effect as the data-role="page" one, like add specific data-transitions. Would that be possible?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps just hide/show the 2 subpage divs via jQuery based on your particular page logic i.e. on click or some other event `$('#content_1').toggle(); $('#content_2').toggle();` remember to also add `#content_2{display:none;}` as CSS to begin with.

Also, if you want the native transitions etc that you get with loading between normal pages you shoudl consider the plugin/widget found here https://github.com/ToddThomson/jQuery-Mobile-Subpage-Widget